# Microsoft Excel Pivot Table Filter - % of Parent Total

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table

I am having trouble with filtering my pivot table/chart.

My objective is to understand the % of those products that have <= 20% DC Share across all Indexes but when I apply a filter for this on my Chart, the values automatically amount to 100%. I only want my chart to show those that have <= 20% share but I also want the ability to filter.

I want the X'd values in the screenshot below to NOT appear in my chart when I filter but I do not want the values to change to 100%:
[SEE HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SFSs.jpg)

If I keep both filters selected, it shows a breakdown of those that are <= 20% and those that are >20% DC Share but if I filter just one category, the graph shows the value at 100%. I suspect it is because it is calculating the sub total of each index. The value option I have selected is "% of Parent Total" - I have tried using the "No Calculation" option and this works, but shows the true value rather than %.

Before and After Filter - https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQxbb.jpg:
[image: Before and After Filter]

Raw Data:
[image: Raw Data]

```
Index
A
A
A
B
B
B
B
B
C
C
C

Product
Green Apple
Red Apple
Banana
Grapes
Tomato
Potato
Leek
Cherries
Cashew Nuts
Rice
Bread

DC share
19%
20%
25%
34%
56%
33%
12%
13%
23%
19%
17%

Product <= 20% DC Share
<=20% DC Share
<=20% DC Share
> 20% DC Share
> 20% DC Share
> 20% DC Share
> 20% DC Share
<=20% DC Share
<=20% DC Share
> 20% DC Share
<=20% DC Share
<=20% DC Share
```

Comment: Please post your raw data in a form that we can copy.

Comment: @jeffreyweir - Hi, is there a recommended method on posting raw data? I can't seem to find the function on the Edit page (I'm new to this site!)

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, your the `Value Field Settings` is **Count of...**, please change to **Sum of...**

[image]

Select the PivotTable and change `Value Field Settings` to **Sum of...**
[image]
[image]